# Send Server Stored PDF File To another Server Via Curl PHP Form Data

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am trying to send a PHP file which is stored on my server to another server via Curl PHP Form Data method.

Usually, it is done by submitting a form and uploading file and sending the same file as form data to Curl PHP endpoint but in this case I have already that file on my server and I am stuck on the part how will I fetch that file and create its form data array and send it API Url as an post method.

Below are some sort of programme I am trying. Out of which one is to create a tmp file and storing data in there and send that data from tmp location to curl form data.

$source = file_get_contents("https://url/employee_manual3.pdf");

```
    $tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'File_');   
    rename($tempFile, $tempFile .= '.pdf');

    file_put_contents($tempFile, $source);

    // var_dump($tempFile);
    // exit;
    
    // $post = array(
    //     "uploadedFile" => "@" . $tempFile, //"@".$tempFile.";type=application/pdf",
    // );

    // var_dump(file_get_contents($tempFile));
    // var_dump(new CURLFILE($tempFile));
    // exit;

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://API_URL',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file' => new CURLFILE($tempFile)),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Bearer API TOKEN HAI MERA',
            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
            'Cookie: MAIN NAHI BATAUNGA'
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can check the answer below on how I managed to pull this off.

```
    // $source = file_get_contents("https://URL/assets/email_images/employee_manual3.pdf");

    $file_path = __DIR__.'/../../../assets/email_images/employee_manual3.pdf';

    // var_dump(__DIR__.'/../../../assets/email_images/employee_manual3.pdf');
    // exit;

    // var_dump(new CURLFILE($file_path, 'application/pdf', 'file'));
    // exit;

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'API URL',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file' => new CURLFILE($file_path, 'application/pdf', 'file')),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).